# String gets auto translated by OS (Android)

Tags: java, android, translation, numberformatexception

I have a POJO, which has a structure like this (i.e. the class is `NameBalance.java`)

```
String name;
String balance; //this String will later be parsed as Double

//getter-setter for name

public void setBalance(String balance){
    this.balance = balance;
}

public String getBalance(){
    return this.balance;
}
```

The object is parsed from an API response.

When I am getting `balance` value from the object (which is a `String`), the value gets automatically translated by the Android OS of the device if the device has a language other than English.

Problem is, if the other language has non-english numeric letters, then I cannot parse it to `Double` ending up throwing a `NumberFormatException`.

I understand that in case of resource `String` , i could set `transalatable="false"` . But what is the solution in my case? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to just store balance as a double in the first instance, use string formatting when you want to display it.

Comment: Thanks i think it is a good idea :)